# Dockerized Neo4J maintaining Volume through restarts somehow?

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Compose and using the standard Neo4j image. I'm not specifying any Volumes to be mounted but when I bring docker down and bring it back up it still has old data. I can't find where/how it is storing this.

I'd like to override it so each new Docker has fresh database. Any ideas?

docker-compose.yml:

```
neo4j:
  image: neo4j:3.0
  ports:
   - "7474:7474"
   - "7687:7687"
  environment:
   - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password
  volumes: []
```

Trying to override any volumes with `volumes: []` but that isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily purge all the data while taking down your `docker-compose` deployment appending the `-v` flag at the end of the command i.e.:

`docker-compose down -v`

This will stop your deployment, delete the related containers and remove the associated volumes.

**EDIT**

As Fryguy said in the comments, you can recreate your anonymous volumes when launching a new deployment with the `-V` flag (capital letter), so:

`docker-compose up -V`

Will recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving data from the previous containers.

Comment: Thanks! I actually think `docker-compose up -V` (Note -v for down and capital -V for up, weird) is doing what I want which is to start up docker with NEW anonymous volumes

Comment: Good catch! I'll update my answer adding this flag I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

After you issue the docker-compose down command, it should remove all of the containers.  Verify that they are removed.

```
docker ps -a
```

You can remove any unattached volumes with:

```
docker volume prune
```

Another thing that I came across was that I had installed Neo4j desktop and while I assumed I was using the docker instance, I was really using a local database. I finally realized this when I shut down my docker container but was still able to hit the database.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior when starting and stopping a container.  The file system is preserved.

If you want to clear out your data, start a new container with

```
docker run
```

With compose, you can use the

```
 --force-recreate
```

flag.